# отправка данных после добавление записи в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте каким макаром заставить запустить код в другом файле после добавления произвольных типов записей? файл отправляет данные из поста в црмку

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta', false );
function save_newpost_meta( $post_id ) {
    // слаг лучше указать единожды и использовать во всех кодах 
    // связанных с типом записи, как это принято в классах
    $slug = 'newpost';
    // Проверяем тип записи, если не boo то выходим.
    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] )
        return;
    **вот тут что писать чтобы запустился файл?**
}
```

UPD.

```
$offer_id = '42';
$seeker_source = '226';

$nameParts = explode(' ', $name); 

$data[0] = [
    'name' => $nameParts[0],
    'family' => empty($nameParts[1]) ? $nameParts[0] : $nameParts[1], //Отредим имя от фамилии пробелом
    'email' => $email,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'notes' => $notes,
    'offer_id' => $offer_id,
    'seeker_source' => $seeker_source,
];

$api = 'https://our/api/api';

$token = getToken($api);

$request = sendRequest($api, $token, $data);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($request);die();
}
function getToken($api)
{
    /**
     * Perform login call, to obtain authorization token
     **********************************************************/

    $login = 'login';
    $password = 'pass';

    $request = json_encode([
        'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
        'id' => 1,  // Request identifier - any random number, response will contain the same identifier
        'method' => 'AuthService.login',
        'params' => [
            // Login credentials of administrator with allowed access to API calls
            'login' => $login,
            'password' => $password
        ]
    ]);

    $headers = [
        'Content-type: application/json'
    ];

    $curl = curl_init($api);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $received_content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $result = json_decode($received_content)->result;
    return $result->token;
}

function sendRequest($api, $token, $data)
{
    /**
     * Perform any other api request using authorization token
     **********************************************************/

    $request = json_encode([
        'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
        'id' => 2,
        'method' => 'Api.Service.apply',
        'params' => $data
    ]);

    $headers = [
        'Content-type: application/json',
        "Authorization: Bearer {$token}"
    ];

    $curl = curl_init($api);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $received_content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return json_decode($received_content)->result;
    
    }
```

Comment: Если знать основы php (да и вообще программирования), то откроется удивительное: запускается не "файл", а "код". Файл подключается.

Comment: @SeVlad вы бы лучше подсказали, смысл то понятен просто не так выразился

Comment: Неужто не понятно, что надо прописать КОД?

Comment: @SeVlad а какой файл добавлять?

Answer (score 0):

ван нужно отправлять данные в crm для этого нужно использовать api.
wp имеет встроенные функции для отправки данных их вам и нужно использовать. так же по этим ссылкам есть примеры работы с ними

[wp_remote_get](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_remote_get)

[wp_remote_post](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_remote_post)

[wp_remote_request](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_remote_request)

Очень полезная статья по работе http api
[HTTP API WordPress](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6462/wordpress-http-api.html)

в вашем случае это будет иметь примерно такой вид

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta', false );

function save_newpost_meta( $post_id ) {
    $slug = 'newpost';
    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }

    // сюда нужно вставить ссылку на эндпоит api
    $url = '';
    // сюда нужно передать аргументы для аутентификации работы с api и добавить контент который вы хотите отправить  
    $args = [];

    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );

    // проверка результата на наличие ошибок
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ){
        echo $response->get_error_message();
    }
    
    // проверка результата на код ответа и сохранение ответа в переменную для дальнейшей обработки если нужно
    if ( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) === 200 ){
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    }
}
```

Comment: Круто, а я хочу отправить json данные, подскажите пожалуйста как например отправить в другой сервис где требует авторизации? в UPD добавил код того самого файла

Comment: для этого вам нужно в аргументах в body добавить ваш json и в headers передать параметр Content-Type со значением  application/json так же испульзуя wp_remote_post либую другую функци из перечисленных вам не нужно использовать curl. ознакомьтесь с описанием работы данных функций. так же добавил в ответ еще одну ссылку на подробное описание по работе с http api